# How can i create a segue that pass data to another view controller only if certain criteria are met

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I want to create a segue to pass data to another view controller but there are certain criteria that must happen for the segue to happen. If possible i would prefer to use the segue Id instead of the dragging method.

this is an example Im trying to accomplish

```
@IBAction func SubmitButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

    if 1<0 {
        // dont perform segue
    }else{
        //Perform segue

        // i want to pass this data in the next VC
        var data = "foo"

        //this is my segue id i want o use to go to the Second VC
        var segueId = "segueForgotPasswordTwo"

        // second VC
        var secondVc = "viewController2"


        // Iwant to to use prepare for segue but im getting errors in the parameters
        prepareForSegue(UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?){


        }

    }
}
```

Comment: That is far too broad - your code sample only confuses me even more. What segue id, what "dragging method"? In general simply pass some data along inside the `prepareForSegue`-method. In there you can put the conditional logic.

Comment: I want to create a form, before the View Controller1 can segue to the next View Controller2 i to verify the form. if the form is empty i want to remain on View Controller1 if it is not empty i want to go segue to the next View Controller. I hope that was able to help

Comment: What is stopping you from doing exactly that? Hook your form submit button action to some IBAction code, do some verification and if the input is valid, trigger the segue.

Comment: i'm with luk2302. i don't really the problem, too... just do it exactly like that. use your code within that else

Comment: @luke2302 I dont understand why down vote my questions the suggestions that were given did not work except for the one below this comment. I understand it sounded like a simple question but my project required me to do it a certain. can you remove the down votes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a bit unclear but I believe this is what you are looking for...

```
    func someFunction(){

        if //some condition {
        //code

        }else if //some condition {
        //code

        } else {
        //perform segue by using the folowing line. Assign the identifier to the segue in the storyboard.
            //Do this by first creating a segue by dragging from a view controller to the destination view controller. Be sure to drag from the VIEWCONTROLLER, to the destination VIEWCONTROLLER. DO NOT just drag from the button. Next, choose the type of segue (eg. show or present modally), and then type in an indentifier for this segue.
        performSegueWithIdentifier("SegueIdentifier", sender: nil)
    }



    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "SegueIdentifier" {

            //now find your view controller that you are seguing to.
            let controller = segue.destinationViewController as! SomeViewController

            //access the properties of your viewController and set them as desired. this is how you will pass data along
            controller.property = someValue

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

## Overview:

1. Hook the segue from the source view controller to the destination view controller (see left side red arrows)
2. Don’t hook it from the button to the destination view controller
3. Create an action for the button to do your custom condition check then perform segue

## Screenshot:

[image]

## Code:

```
var data = "foo"

    @IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
        
        let someCondition = true
        
        if someCondition {
            performSegueWithIdentifier("showGreen", sender: self)
        }
        else {
            performSegueWithIdentifier("showPink", sender: self)
        }
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "showGreen" {

            let greenVC = segue.destinationViewController as! GreenViewController
            // Make sure the data variable exists in GreenViewController
            greenVC.data = data

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can implement the `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier` function in your ViewController. When the segue is triggered, this function can cancel the segue if it returns `false`, so you can simply include whatever logic is required in this function and return true/false as appropriate.